# Silverlight designer error

Tags: silverlight

Whenever I open my Visual Studio 2010 Silverlight designer for xaml  I am getting this error.

System.NullReferenceException Object reference not set to an instance of an object. at Microsoft.Expression.Platform.Silverlight.SilverlightDomainManager.CreateDomainCore() at Microsoft.Expression.Platform.Silverlight.SilverlightDomainManager.CreateDomainInitial() at Microsoft.Expression.Platform.Silverlight.SilverlightPlatformCreator.Initialize() at MS.Internal.Platform.SilverlightPlatformImpl.Initialize() at MS.Internal.Package.VSIsolationProviderService.RemoteReferenceProxy.EnsurePlatformInitialized() at MS.Internal.Package.VSIsolationProviderService.RemoteReferenceProxy.EnsurePlatformInitialized() at MS.Internal.Package.VSIsolationProviderService.CreateIsolationProvider(String originalIdentifier, Boolean isGlobal, String identity, FrameworkName frameworkName, AssemblyName appAssemblyName, IVsHierarchy hierarchy) at MS.Internal.Package.VSIsolationProviderService.CreateIsolationProviderWorker(String identifier, IServiceProvider provider) at MS.Internal.Package.VSIsolationProviderService.CreateIsolationProvider(String identifier, IServiceProvider provider) at MS.Internal.Providers.VSDesignerContext.CreateIsolationProvider(IServiceProvider provider, IVsHierarchy hierarchy) at MS.Internal.Providers.VSDesignerContext.<>c_DisplayClass1.b_0(IsolationProviderProxy i) at MS.Internal.Providers.IsolationProviderProxy.get_RealProvider() at MS.Internal.Providers.IsolationProviderProxy.add_UnhandledException(UnhandledExceptionEventHandler value) at MS.Internal.Designer.DesignerPane.LoadDesignerView()

Note:- I saw lot of references in online & in stackoverflow. Nothings works for me.

Comment: It seems its a microsoft expressinon blend problem. Have you recently open your XAML in Microsoft Expression Blend if so, check your references. It seems some Blend dll's missing.

Comment: Here no way I am not talking about Expression Blend.

Answer (score 0):

In this forum
http://forums.silverlight.net/t/168508.aspx kakone says "There were some old versions of Silverlight assemblies into the GAC.I used gacutil to remove all Version=2.0.5.0 silverlight assemblies. "

So maybe old assemblies cause conflicts.

See also

http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/543205/silverlight-rc-4-designer-dontwork

Answer (score 0):

i dont know if you got the answer or not, but i had a similar issue a while back and here is what i did

1. Goto add/remove programs.
2. unistall both silverlight components. i.e. Silverlight and its SDK
3. [Download](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=18149) this file and install it.
4. Restart Visual Studio, and now it should work fine